# what is meant by kinking the cable?

Tags: networking

What is meant by kinking the cable. I saw at https://superuser.com/a/367001/252080 the first thing shared was not to kink the cable. Can somebody explain what is kinking and why should not one do it. If somebody has any images to go with it, much better as well.

The second bit about "avoid tight or sharp bends; for UTP the bend radius should be at least 1"." . Can somebody explain to me what is this bend radius as well.

Thank you for your patience.

Update :- I did get some part of the answer just after I wrote. Bend radius is this :-

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bend_radius

Kinking also seems to be somehow damaging the cable but how does that damage happens is not shared/explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A kink is a twist or a bend. [kink](http://www.crn.com.au/Gallery/318930,in-pictures-common-network-wiring-mistakes.aspx/5)

A kink in a cable may change slightly the impedance of the cable but I don't think this would be a very big problem with the level of electricity we have in an ethernet cable. This would be a more a problem for bigger cables like submarine cables for example.

The main problem of a kink is that with time it can damage the cable like the picture below [image: this].

Comment: Also note that it is not possible to remove a kink from a cable by straightening it.

Answer (score 0):

A severe enough bend or kink could break the wire(s) inside (which is obviously bad).  Can also happen from being bent repeatedly in the same spot.

Comment: Then for corners, what would be the good/better practice to have. Are there any sort of connectors (like in plumbing) which should be used?

Comment: just keep the bending radius wide enough. A good point of reference for running and securing cable is the TP-76300, section J: https://ebiznet.sbc.com/sbcnebs/Documents/TP76300/  Those rules are designed for uptime environments.