# What are the factors for Bad Ethernet connection?

Tags: networking, router, ethernet

I just made someone install RJ45 from my Living Room to my Office on two floors above the current one. Cable is Cat6 for what is worth.

Thing is that when I put cables on the two ends (one to the router and another one to another device), the light on the router lights up but a lot often it comes down and keeps off.

I tried several cables in both ends and even tried to connect the computer directly to it but it doesn't get IP.

I read the specs on the Cat 6 and even to get 10GBASE-T I need 33 meters (or 108ft) at the worst conditions (which I don't think I am) and I don't think I'm near that, yet, it doesn't work.

For what is worth, the router does work. I'm able to get medium strength wifi signal from it, and directly connecting to the router itself (without the new cable that goes through the walls) works perfectly. Things just doesn't show up on the DHCP table of the router when connected with this new cable.

Main reason for asking this is cause I can see a light turning on (though it's not 100% consistent) which means network activity going on.

So, here's my question:

What are the factors for a lousy connection? What should I be looking for in order to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: does your installation consist of wall sockets? it is possible to miswire the cable in a socket.

Comment: Damaged cable is probably #1.  See http://superuser.com/questions/366735/does-the-length-of-cat6-cable-make-a-difference-in-a-home-network/367001#367001  And it seems like you have already proven that it's the new cable.

Comment: It is a wall socket. I've checked the connection on both ends and cables seem to be in the right order

Comment: wall socket always give headache, did you use the puncher tool? Do you have a network tester to test if the wire are correctly connected?

Comment: The light doesnt mean a connection, it just means there is power.

Comment: @sawdust it turned out to be the cable. There was a section where it was a little bit more stretched than it should. Made it nicer and the data started to flow.