# Homemade Ethernet Cable Not Working Properly

Tags: networking, ethernet, cable

I run an Ethernet cable through my walls and crimped at both ends as a twisted cable:

```
Orange stripe
Orange
Green stripe
Blue
Blue stripe
Green
Brown stripe
Brown
```

As I need to connect my router to an access point located elsewhere in the house (I'm extending WiFi signal).

I noticed the ap wasn't working properly thus I figured out it was the cable. I'm testing it connecting the cable from router to laptop. OK with a known working cable but it "blinks fine" with my homemade cable. By blinks fine I mean it shows OK for a second (the internet icon on my laptop) then it goes disconnected. It keeps going like this. Also the cable used to be fine a few days ago... I don't understand what could be the issue...

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/366735/does-the-length-of-cat6-cable-make-a-difference-in-a-home-network/367001#367001

Comment: Any mice chewing the cable, they love network cables.

Comment: There's probably something wrong with the crimp. It's easy to make an ethernet cable that is just barely functional but fails after it has been wiggled around because the wires pull out of the crimp slightly (or never really made good contact). Are all eight conductors on both ends fully inserted into the connector? If one of the connectors is iffy, try cutting it off and crimping on a new one. A flaky cable may "blink OK" because it's good enough for presence detection or speed/duplex autonegotiation, but not good enough to reliably carry data.

Comment: Closely examine both ends, and see if the metal contacts are pushed all the way in. Also, make sure all wires are pushed all the way to the end of the channel, or at least far enough that the contacts easily make a good connection. Chances are, with examination, you will be able to fix it by simply redoing one end.

Answer (score 0):

Your Ethernet colors is correct.
To know exactly what happening inside your cable plug a laptop to the first side - other side connected to a router
Open CMD command and ping your router IP

```
ping 192.168.x.x
```

Check if there is any lost packets
Make sure your Ethernet cable not close to any AC power lines.
If your connections drop down a lot then replace your RJ45 to a new one.

Answer (score 0):

The order of your wires is correct. 
Chances are you have a bad connection on one end (or worse yet, a bad cable.)

Closely examine both ends, and see if the metal contacts are pushed all the way in. Also, make sure all wires are pushed all the way to the end of the channel, or at least far enough that the contacts easily make a good connection. You will likely be able to fix the problem by redoing only one end.

If you can't see that one end is bad, then replace both ends. If that doesn't fix it, your cable is probably bad, and that isn't really fixable.