# outdoor rated cat 6 FTP cable not connecting at 1Gbps too long? (50m)

Tags: ethernet, gigabit-ethernet, interference, cat6

I have using a 50m cat 6 FTP shielded cable to connect downstairs with upstairs. The cable is run outdoor for convenience... problem is the cable does not connect at 1Gbps but at 100Mbps instead... :(

I thought it was electrical interference or other cables (ethernet, coaxial cable) .. so I made sure to isolate the cable from the other cables for testing but I still can't connect to 1Gbps.

I tested my switch and router to make sure it is gigabit and it is.

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/366735/does-the-length-of-cat6-cable-make-a-difference-in-a-home-network/367001#367001

Answer (score 0):

Based on my personal experience, I would take a cable tester (between $5 for a basic tester and $50, depending on features) and double-check all 4 pairs are indeed connected. If only 3 or 2 pairs of wires are connected, then you won't get 1Gbps.